# Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on null in ..../abstractmodel.php 98

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I try to learn how to make MVC model, but i have the following errors:
Notice: Sorry no method prepare has been found in ......./pdodatabasehandler.php 27
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on null in ..../abstractmodel.php 98

**databasehandler.php**

```
   <?php
namespace BATRAHOSTMVC\Lib\Database;
/**
 * Description of DatabaseHandler
 *
 * @author Mohamed Hassan Elmetwaly
 * 25-03-2017
 * mhe.developer@gmail.com
 */
abstract class DatabaseHandler {
    const DATABASE_DRIVER_POD = 1;
    const DATABASE_DRIVER_MYSQLI = 2;

    private function __construct() {

    }
    abstract protected static function init();
    abstract protected static function getInstance();
    public static function factory()
    {
      //  $driver = DATABASE_CONN_DRIVER;
     //  if($driver == self::DATABASE_DRIVER_POD)
      // {
          return PDODatabaseHandler::getInstance();

      // } else if ($driver == self::DATABASE_DRIVER_MYSQLI)
     //  {
      //     return MySQLiDatabaseHandler::getInstance();
      // }       
    }
}
```

**pdodatabasehandler.php**

```
    <?php
namespace BATRAHOSTMVC\Lib\Database;
/**
 * Description of pdodatabasehandler

 * @author Mohamed Hassan Elmetwaly
 * 25-03-2017
 * mhe.developer@gmail.com
 */


class PDODatabaseHandler extends DatabaseHandler
{
    private static $_instance;
    private static $_handler;

    private function __construct() {
        self::init();
    }
    //public function __call($name, $arguments) {}

   public function __call($name, $arguments) {
       if(method_exists($this, $name))
       {
           $this->$name($arguments);
       } else {
           trigger_error('Sorry no method '. $name. ' has been found');
       }

   }    

    protected static function init(){
        try{

            self::$_handler = new \PDO(
                    'mysql:host='.DATABASE_HOST_NAME.';dbname='.DATABASE_DB_NAME,DATABASE_USER_NAME,
                    DATABASE_PASSW0RD);
            //var_dump(self::$_handler);
            //self::$_handler = new pdo("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test", 'root', 'rootbootroot');
            //return 'Connected';

        } catch (\PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage( ) ." | ". $e->getCode( ) ;

        }

    }
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(self::$_instance === null){
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }



}
```

**abstractmodel.php**

```
   <?php
namespace BATRAHOSTMVC\Models;
use BATRAHOSTMVC\Lib\Database\DatabaseHandler;
//echo DATABASE_DB_NAME;
/**
 * Description of abstractmodel
 * @author Mohamed Hassn Elmetwaly (25-03-2017)
 * mhe.developer@gmail.com
 */
class AbstractModel 
{
    const DATA_TYPE_BOOL = \PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
    const DATA_TYPE_STR = \PDO::PARAM_STR;
    const DATA_TYPE_INT = \PDO::PARAM_INT;
    const DATA_TYPE_DECIMAL = 4;
    const DATA_TYPE_DATE = 5;
    /*
    public static function viewTableSchema()
    {
        return static::$tableSchema;
    }
     * 
     */
    // we make path by reference 
    private function prepareValues(\PDOStatement &$stmt)
    {
          foreach (static::$tableSchema as $columnName => $type)
        {
            if($type == 4)
            {
                $sanitizedValue = filter_var($this->$columnName, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
                $stmt->bindValue(":{$columnName}", $sanitizedValue);
            }
            else
            {
                $stmt->bindValue(":{$columnName}", $this->$columnName,  $type);
            }

        }      
    }

        private static function buildNameParametersSQL()
    {
        $nameParams = '';
        //$columnName (Column Name) => $type (Column datatype)
        foreach (static::$tableSchema as $columnName => $type)
        {
            $nameParams .= $columnName. ' = :'.$columnName. ', ';
        }
        return trim($nameParams, ', ');
    }

    private static function create()
    {
        //global $connection;

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO '. static::$tableName . ' SET '. self::buildNameParametersSQL();
        $stmt = DatabaseHandler::factory()->prepare($sql);
        $this->prepareValues($stmt);
        return $stmt->execute(); // true of false
    }

    private static function update()
    {
       // global $connection; 
        $sql = 'UPDATE '. static::$tableName . ' SET '. self::buildNameParametersSQL(). ' WHERE '. static::$primaryKey .' = '.$this->{static::$primaryKey};
      //  $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
        //$stmt = DatabaseHandler::factory()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt = DatabaseHandler::factory()->prepare($sql);
        $this->prepareValues($stmt);
        return $stmt->execute(); // true of false
    }

    public function save()
    {
        return $this->{static::$primaryKey} === null ? $this->create() : $this->update();
    }

    public static function delete()
    {
      //  global $connection; 
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM '. static::$tableName . ' WHERE '. static::$primaryKey .' = '.$this->{static::$primaryKey};
       // $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $stmt = DatabaseHandler::factory()->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt->execute(); // true of false
    }

    public static function getAll()
    {
       // global $connection; 
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '. static::$tableName;
        //$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $stmt = DatabaseHandler::factory()->prepare($sql);
        //return $connection->execute() === true ? $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS | \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Employee', array('name', 'age', 'address', 'tax', 'salary')) : false;
        //using fetchAll with this paramaters return values as OBJECT Of class which returned by get_called_calss() which called this method
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS | \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, get_called_class(), array_keys(static::$tableSchema));
        return is_array($result) && !empty($result) === true ? $result : false;
    }

    public static function getByPk($pk)
    {
        //global $connection; 
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '. static::$tableName. ' WHERE '. static::$primaryKey .' = '.$pk;
        //$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
        //$stmt = DatabaseHandler::factory()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt = DatabaseHandler::factory()->prepare($sql);
        //return $connection->execute() === true ? $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS | \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Employee', array('name', 'age', 'address', 'tax', 'salary')) : false;
        //using fetchAll with this paramaters return values as OBJECT Of class which returned by get_called_calss() which called this method
        if($connection->execute() === true)
        {
            $obj = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS | \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, get_called_class(), array_keys(static::$tableSchema));
            return array_shift($obj);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static function get($sql, $options = array())
    {
        /*
         * example:
         * $emps = Employee::get(
         * 'SELECT name, age FROM employees WHERE age = :age',
         * array(
         * 'age' => array(Employee::DATA_TYPE_INT, 34)
         * )
         * )
         * var_dump($emps)
         */

        //global $connection;
        //$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $stmt = DatabaseHandler::factory()->prepare($sql);
        if(!empty($options))
        {
         foreach ($options as $columnName => $type)
        {
            //$type[0] = datatype, $type[1] = columname
            if($type[0] == 4)
            {
                $sanitizedValue = filter_var($type[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
                $stmt->bindValue(":{$columnName}", $sanitizedValue);
            }
            else
            {
                $stmt->bindValue(":{$columnName}", $type[1], $type[0]);
            }

        }            
        }
        $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS | \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, get_called_class(), array_keys(static::$tableSchema));
                return is_array($result) && !empty($result) === true ? $result : false;
        /*        
        if(method_exists(get_called_class(), '__construct')){
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS | \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, get_called_class(), array_keys(static::$tableSchema));
        //return is_array($result) && !empty($result) === true ? $result : false;
        } else {
        $result =$stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_called_class());    
        }
        if((is_array($result) && !empty($result))){
            $generator = function() use ($result){};
            return $generator;
        }
        return false;

         */

    }
}
```

**employeecontroller.php**

```
    <?php

/**
 * Description of abstractcontroller
 *
 * @author Mohamed Hassn Elmetwaly (25-03-2017)
 * mhe.developer@gmail.com
 */

namespace BATRAHOSTMVC\Controllers;
use BATRAHOSTMVC\Models\EmployeeModel;

class EmployeeController extends AbstractController
{

    public function defaultAction()
    {
        //EmployeeModel::getAll();
        var_dump(EmployeeModel::getAll());
        $this->_view();
    }
}
```

**employeemodel.php**

```
   <?php
namespace BATRAHOSTMVC\Models;
//use BATRAHOSTMVC\Models\AbstractModel;
//use BATRAHOSTMVC\Models\AbstractModel;
/**
 * Description of employee
 * @author Mohamed Hassn Elmetwaly (25-03-2017)
 * mhe.developer@gmail.com
 */

class EmployeeModel extends AbstractModel
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $address;
    public $tax;
    public $salary;

    public static $db;
    protected static $tableName = 'employees';
    protected static $tableSchema = array(
      'name'        => self::DATA_TYPE_STR,
      'age'        => self::DATA_TYPE_INT,
      'address'        => self::DATA_TYPE_STR,
      'tax'        => self::DATA_TYPE_DECIMAL,
      'salary'        => self::DATA_TYPE_DECIMAL
    );
    protected static $primaryKey = 'id';
    public function __construct($name, $age, $address, $tax, $salary) {


        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->tax = $tax;
        $this->salary = $salary;


    }
    public function __get($prop){
        $this->$prop;
    }
    public function getTableName(){
        return self::$tableName;
    }

}
```

**autoload.php**

```
  <?php
namespace BATRAHOSTMVC\LIB;

/*
 * Applcation Constants
 */
/*
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('APP_PATH', dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).DS.'..');

define('PS', PATH_SEPARATOR);
define('CONTROLLER_PATH', APP_PATH.DS.'controllers');
define('MODEL_PATH', APP_PATH.DS.'models');
//echo CONTROLLER_PATH;
$path = get_include_path().PS.CONTROLLER_PATH.PS.MODEL_PATH;
set_include_path($path);

 */
class Autoload
{
    public static function autoload($classname)
    {
      /* in Explanation */
      $classname = str_replace('BATRAHOSTMVC', '',$classname);
      $classname = str_replace('\\', '/', $classname);
      $classname = $classname.'.php';
      $classname = strtolower($classname);
        if(file_exists(APP_PATH.$classname))
        {
             require_once APP_PATH.$classname;
        }
     /*   
     $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $classname);
     $classFile = APP_PATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.strtolower($class).'.php';
     if(file_exists($classFile))
        {
             require $classFile;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

      */
    }
}
spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__.'\Autoload::autoload');
```

**frontcontroller.php**

```
    <?php

namespace BATRAHOSTMVC\LIB;

class FrontController
{
    const NOT_FOUND_ACTION = 'notFoundAction';
    const NOT_FOUND_CONTROLLER = 'BATRAHOSTMVC\Controllers\NotFoundController';

    private $_controller = 'index';
    private $_action = 'default';
    private $_params = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_parseUrl();
    }

        private function _parseUrl()
    {
        $url = explode('/', trim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH),'/'), 3);
        var_dump($url);
        if(isset($url[0]) && $url[0] !='')
        {
            $this->_controller = $url[0];
        }
        if(isset($url[1]) && $url[1] !='')
        {
            $this->_action = $url[1];
        }
        if(isset($url[2]) && $url[2] !='')
        {
            $this->_params = explode('/', $url[2]);
        }            
       // @list($this->_controller, $this->_action, $this->_params) = explode('/', trim($url, '/'),3);
      //  $this->_params = explode('/', $this->_params);
        var_dump($this);
    }

    public function dispatch()
    {
       $controllerClassName = 'BATRAHOSTMVC\Controllers\\'.ucfirst($this->_controller).'Controller';
       $actionName = $this->_action.'Action';
       if(!class_exists($controllerClassName))
       {
           $controllerClassName = self::NOT_FOUND_CONTROLLER;
       }
       $controller = new $controllerClassName();
       if(!method_exists($controller, $actionName))
       {
          $this->_action = $actionName = self::NOT_FOUND_ACTION;
       }
       $controller->setController($this->_controller);
       $controller->setAction($this->_action);
       $controller->setParams($this->_params);
       $controller->$actionName();
    }
}
```

I attached my files in the following link
http://www.mediafire.com/file/mdbxj5o3f6hd3gz/mvcyahia%285-4-2017%29.rar

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not downloading a rar, and neither will anyone else here. [Edit] your question and post the _relevant_ code. Also voting to close for lack of code posted. You are obviously attempting to call a method on a null object.

Comment: Before attempting something as complex as a MVC application, you should invest some time in basic debugging skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static function getInstance() {
if(self::$_instance === null){
    self::$_instance = new self();
}

 // here was the confusing the old value was  return self::$_instance
return self::$_handler; 

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your database / query object is null. So find how you call the database object so you can call its method.

Your code shows no prepare() method defined for your db class.

You are setting your PDODatabaseHandler::_handler property to the PDO, but when you are returning self(). Get it?